# gradle set ear appendix based on taskgraph

Tags: java, properties, gradle, ear

I'm using Gradle to build an EAR file. In Gradle I've defined dummy tasks and I use those to read properties from properties-files, like this:

```
task configure() {
    // load the default properties:
    loadProperties "configure.properties"

    // override them if a specific dummy task was found
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
        if (taskGraph.hasTask(configureForFallback)) {
            loadProperties 'configure.fallback.properties'
        }
    }
}
```

`loadProperties` is a custom method. It is then easy to access the properties in Gradle execution phase. I'd like to use one of those properties to influence the name of the EAR file, like this:

```
ear {
    if (this.properties.containsKey("CUSTOMAPPENDIX")) {
        appendix = "${CUSTOMAPPENDIX}"
    }
}
```

This doesn't work though, as the `appendix` property is read in the `configuration` phase, and we set it in `execution` phase. Can I somehow overwrite the `getAppendixName()` of the `ear` task?

I could probably pass the `CUSTOMAPPENDIX` property on the Gradle command-line, but I'd like to have all configuration for a specific target in one file. Any other ideas how I could implement this?

Comment: You aren't (and shouldn't be) setting the properties in the execution phase. As-is, the `configure` task doesn't make sense. It should be removed and only its body left in the build script. As to why this doesn't work, perhaps the configuration order is wrong, or perhaps `appendix` is a fallback property, in which case it will only get set at the end of the configuration phase (`taskGraph.whenReady`). Without more context, it's hard to say how to fix this without introducing a hack (which would be `ear.doFirst { if ... }`).

Comment: It appears that you are layering a properties file based build language on top of Gradle's build language, which is not something I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks @peter-niederwieser, you gave some very useful hints. I've done away with the property files and converted them to simple gradle files which can be selected using a command-line property instead of dummy tasks:

    if (project.hasProperty('local')) {
        apply from: "configure.local.gradle"
    } else if (project.hasProperty('fallback')) {
        apply from: "configure.fallback.gradle"
    } else {
        apply from: "configure.prod.gradle"
    }

No nasty ear-hacks required! :)